# How to achieve sound like this in DAW?

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects

Do you know how can I achieve effect like in 1:10 min :

it's somekind of wobble stop / shaking sound...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you will need an instrument to use in the DAW, Like Native Instrument's Massive(VSTi) for example. With this you can produce the chord, and apply the necassary modulation quite easily.

The effect is applied simply by modulating the cutoff frequency of a Low Pass Filter(which the chord sound is passing through). A [Low Frequency Oscillator(LFO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-frequency_oscillation) and an envelope are most likely used as the modulation source.

There are two stages of modulation involved: The **LFO** modulates the filter's **cutoff frequency** to give the 'wobbling' effect, and an **envelope** modulates the **rate** of the LFO to give the 'slowing down' effect.

Note: In place of the envelope, a second LFO could be used, or it could be done by automating the LFO's rate. In sound synthesis, there can be different techniques that achieve the same effect.

[How to use a LFO(You Tube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4eE8-ZxZ4M)
[Synth School, Part 1: Analogue Oscillators, Filters & LFOs(SOS)](https://www.soundonsound.com/sos/1997_articles/jun97/synthschool1.html)
[Wikipedia Page - Synthesizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthesizer)

Answer (score 1):

This synth sounds a lot like massive.
The key to this kind of sound are the polysaw waveforms
which are many saws of different tones into a wavetable,
this allows you creating notes with rich tunings.
To start with here are Massive settings that could be useful:

**OSC/FILTER**

- Polysaw I (0 tone) and II (+12 tone).
- you can add  a sub bass like a sine or a triangle (-12 Tone).
- Sine or triangle LFO on the cutoff or/and intensity.
- Wavetable to the minimum.

**EFFECT**

- 75 % wet on the TTube.
- 7 to 10 % wet and 30 % size on the reverb.